# Getting error "pipesCount of undefined" on bitbucket deployment

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

Getting this error on the deployment of nodejs project:

Type Error --------------------------------------------- TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipesCount' of undefined at ReadStream.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:637:13) at Readable. (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/lazystream/lib/lazystream.js:33:12) at Readable.instance (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/lazystream/lib/lazystream.js:18:14) at Readable.read (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/*stream_readable.js:443:10) at resume* (/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:790:12) at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)

It's from the bitbucket site. Suddenly coming from last day.**strong text**